# What's the programming language of this code snippet

Tags: sql

```
var newSqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = " + myId;
```

I found this code in the top answer in the following link:
[What is Ad Hoc Query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2460954/what-is-ad-hoc-query)

What's this language?

Comment: that one is javascript

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because language identification questions are not a good fit for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Could be other languages as well. Also as an aside: prone to injection, if myId is a user-supplied value.

Comment: @nhgrif sorry about that, I met this problem when I search for SQL, and I have no idea what's language it is, I thought it was a variation of SQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ever heard of Javascript? This is backend JS. Probably Node.